# Easiest way to separate a string by spaces?

Tags: c++, string

It's been a long time since I've used C++, been using Javascript in my free time and now I'm not sure exactly what I remember.

Basically I just need to separate a string into parts by looking at the spaces.

All the links I've seen are homemade functions, but I could have sworn there was a way to do it using the standard library by using streams, but again, I'm having a tough time recalling it and my google results aren't helping either.

Keep in mind that it isn't a stream I am taking from, it's just a string like "Bob Accountant 65 retired" and I have to extract each item in the string to its own data field. I've been messing with ifstreams and ofstreams but I'm not even sure what I'm doing, having forgot the syntax for it.

Comment: `strtok` can be used. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: How would I convert my string into a char pointer, though?

Comment: `std::string::c_str ()` will return a null-terminated string for use in C stdlib functions that require null-terminated strings (such as strtok). Be aware that `strtok (...)` is ***not thread-safe*** in its *usual* form, so the answers below that suggest using the C++ stdlib are probably more versatile/robust.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) is the C-style way to do it. You might be thinking of using a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), e.g.:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string input = "foo bar baz  quxx\nducks";
    std::stringstream ss(input);

    std::string word;
    while (ss >> word) {
        std::cout << word << '\n';
    }
}
```

When run, that displays:

```
foo
bar
baz
quxx
ducks
```

If you want to read data from a `std::stringstream` (or any type of `std::istream`, really) into a specific data type, you can follow @JerryCoffin's excellent suggestion of overloading the stream `operator>>` for your data type:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Employee {
    std::string name;
    std::string title;
    int age;
    std::string status;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Employee &e) {
    return is >> e.name >> e.title >> e.age >> e.status;
}

int main() {
    std::string input = "Bob Accountant 65 retired";
    std::stringstream ss(input);

    Employee e;
    ss >> e;

    std::cout << "Name: " << e.name
        << " Title: " << e.title
        << " Age: " << e.age
        << " Status: " << e.status
        << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What would I do if I just wanted to put them in their own data fields, not display them to the console?

Comment: use std::vector<string> stringVect; Instead of calling cout, you should call stringVect.push_back()

Comment: @user2419560: I've updated this answer to include a second example of reading data into a struct.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without an explicit loop like this:

```
string s = "Bob Accountant 65 retired";
vector<string> vs;
istringstream iss(s);
copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(vs));
```

`std::copy` reads everything from the string stream created on the third line, and pushes it into the vector created on the second line.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/Uy0n3W).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of things, you're trying to read a logical record from a string. For that, I'd do something like this:

```
struct record { 
    std::string name;
    std::string position;
    int age;
    std::string status;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, record &r) { 
    return i >> r.name >> r.position >> r.age >> r.status;
}
```

This lets you read data from a `stringstream` to a `record` of the specified fields. It'll also, incidentally, let you read `record` objects from other types of streams as well (e.g., from a file using an `fstream`).